# PositionTargetGlobal failed because no origin

Tags: px4

When I launch the `mavros_posix_sitl.launch` in px4, it always warns that:

> "PositionTargetGlobal failed because no origin"

This leads to the inaccurate flight altitude of UAV in gazebo.

How to solve this problem? I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to PX4's **EKF2 not having an origin set** when starting the SITL.

Throught the mavlink console (if you dont have one started, just execute PX4-Autopilot/Tools/mavlink_shell.py pointing to the correct port), you can set a specific origin using the **commander set_ekf_origin** command and specifying the latitude, longitude and altitude, which will remove the warnings.

Once set, you can also save that origin by [saving and loading your parameters](https://docs.px4.io/main/en/advanced/parameters_and_configurations.html).

Comment: How can I set the EKF origin if the commander  (of PX4 v1.11.3) is not showing the function "set_ekf_origin"?